# thread boost cannot resolve overloaded function

Tags: multithreading, function, pointers, boost

I want to create a new thread which will run a function, but When I compile the terminal display the following error message :

```
g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp -O0 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -std=gnu++0x  -lboost_filesystem -lboost_log_setup -lboost_log -lboost_chrono -lboost_thread -lz -lpthread -ldl -lm  
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:35:13: error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I can't give you my whole code because stackoverflow refuse to post the message if I include code inside.
Here is a sample :

```
void foo(); 

boost::thread t(foo);
```

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Clearly if `foo` is overloaded you're not showing us all the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is a static method, you need to use bind() (you need bind() whenever you either launch non-static methods).

Example:

```
class Worker {
    int returnValue_;
public:
    inline void Run() {
        //...
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(2));
        returnValue_ = 3;
}
    inline int getValue() const {
        return returnValue_;
    }
};

Worker worker;
boost::thread th (boost::bind(&Worker::Run, &worker));
```

Comment: The function bind is usefull when you have a function with arguments. In my case the function I want to pass to the thread constructor doesn't have any and it is a non member function.

Comment: Actually boost can [do that without the explicit bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor): `boost::thread th (&Worker::Run, &worker);`